# SELECT just one FROM the LEFT JOINTs +mySQL

Tags: mysql, left-join

Got following Tables in my SQL-Database (simplified):

Table **Blogs**:

```
+----+----------------------+----------+
| ID |         Date         | TitleGer |
+----+----------------------+----------+
| 1  | 2017-04-28 15:09:46  | Huhu     |
| 2  | 2017-04-28 15:16:18  | Miau     |
| 3  | 2017-04-28 15:17:14  | Kleff    |
+----+----------------------+----------+
```

Table **PicturesJoin**:

```
+-------------+---------+---------------------+
|  IDPicture  | IDBlog  |        Date         |
+-------------+---------+---------------------+
|         86  |      1  | 2017-06-28 17:41:11 |
|         87  |      1  | 2017-06-28 17:41:11 |
+-------------+---------+---------------------+
```

Table **Pictures**:

```
+------+-------------------------+---------------------+
|  ID  |        Filename         |        Date         |
+------+-------------------------+---------------------+
|  86  | 20170512200326_320.jpg  | 2017-05-12 20:03:26 |
|  87  | 20170512200326_384.jpg  | 2017-05-12 20:03:30 |
+------+-------------------------+---------------------+
```

PictureJoin "joins" the Picture with the Blog-Table. Now I use following SQL-Command to joine these two Tables (Blog - PictureJoin) / (PictureJoin - Pictures) together.

```
SELECT
  Blogs.ID,
  Blogs.Date,
  TitleGer,
  Pictures.Filename
FROM
  Blogs
LEFT JOIN
  PicturesJoin ON PicturesJoin.IDBlog = Blogs.ID
LEFT JOIN
  Pictures ON Pictures.ID = PicturesJoin.IDPicture
ORDER BY
  DATE DESC
```

The result might look like that:

```
+------+----------------------+-----------+------------------------+
|  ID  |        Date          | TitleGer  |       Filename         |
+------+----------------------+-----------+------------------------+
|   1  | 2017-06-28 15:09:46  | Huhu      | 20170512200326_320.jpg |
|   1  | 2017-06-28 15:09:46  | Huhu      | 20170512200326_384.jpg |
|   2  | 2017-04-28 15:16:18  | Miau      | NULL                   |
|   3  | 2017-04-28 15:17:14  | Kleff     | NULL                   |
+------+----------------------+-----------+------------------------+
```

He makes a cross-product out of the available Pictures, which is also logical. But I want him to just use the first Picture he finds. In the end it should look like that:

```
+------+----------------------+-----------+------------------------+
|  ID  |        Date          | TitleGer  |       Filename         |
+------+----------------------+-----------+------------------------+
|   1  | 2017-06-28 15:09:46  | Huhu      | 20170512200326_320.jpg |
|   2  | 2017-04-28 15:16:18  | Miau      | NULL                   |
|   3  | 2017-04-28 15:17:14  | Kleff     | NULL                   |
+------+----------------------+-----------+------------------------+
```

Tried several hours but couldn't get it to work. Please help!

Comment: How do you define "the first Picture he finds"?

Comment: You're naming policy is bonkers

Comment: Yeah i know... :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest approach may be to select one IDPicture per IDBlog from PicturesJoin only:

```
SELECT
  b.ID,
  b.Date,
  b.TitleGer,
  p.Filename
FROM Blogs b
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT 
    IDBlog, 
    MIN(IDPicture) AS IDPicture
  FROM PicturesJoin 
  GROUP BY IDBlog
) pj ON pj.IDBlog = b.ID
LEFT JOIN Pictures p ON p.ID = pj.IDPicture
ORDER BY b.Date DESC;
```

Comment: Thanks alot! Awesome!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT b.ID,b.Date,b.TitleGer,p.Filename
FROM Blogs b
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT main_table.*
    FROM PicturesJoin main_table LEFT JOIN PicturesJoin child_table
     ON (main_table.IDBlog= child_table.IDBlog AND main_table.IDPicture> child_table.IDPicture)
    WHERE child_table.id IS NULL
)
OUTER_TABLE ON OUTER_TABLE .IDBlog = b.ID
LEFT JOIN Pictures p ON p.ID = pj.IDPicture
ORDER BY b.Date DESC;
```

Try above query.

Comment: Tried to run your code, but it throws some errors with "#1146 - Table 'DB1.IDPicture' doesn't exist". Tried to solve it but I don't even understand your code ^^ (which is not a miracle because I'm not really good in SQL-Selections)

Comment: Now he throws "#1054 - Unknown column 'child_table.id' in 'where clause'". I think its because of my crazy name-giving to cause confusion hehe